# How to prove this statement about Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty b_i(x-1)^i$. The convergence domain of $f$ is $M$ and the convergence domain of $g$ is $N$. $M\cap N\ne\Phi $ and $M\cap N$ is bounded. If there are infinite points $c_1,c_2,\dots ,c_n, \dots $ in $M\cap N$ such that $f(c_i)=g(c_i)$, then can we say that $f(x)=g(x),\forall x\in M\cap N$ ?

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x),\forall x\in M\cap N$. It suffices to prove that $h\equiv0$. We can find a convergent subseries in $\{c_n\}$, then $h(c_i)=0,\forall i$. Suppose $\{c_n\}$ converges to $c$. If $c\in M\cap N$, then by the theorem below

**Theorem.** *Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function in a region $\Omega$ that
vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point in $\Omega$. Then
$f$ is identically $0$.*

We consider $f$ and $g$ as functions of complex variables, and the convergence domain of $f$ is $L$ and the convergence domain of $g$ is $K$, then $h=f-g\equiv0\ $  in $L\cap K$, and $M\cap N\subset L\cap K$, so $h\equiv0\ $ in $M\cap N$.

However, if $c\notin M\cap N$, I don't know how to prove, is it wrong in this case?

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to make use of the fact that $M$ and $N$ are disks around $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, but how to make use of that fact? Can you add more details?

Comment: this is called the isolated zeroes principle, and a quick google search should give you plenty of references

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to prove is true, basically exactly because of the case you're stuck on. The hypothesis about the limit being inside the domain is crucial in the principle of isolated zeroes! Consider eg the Taylor series of $f(x) = \sin(1 / (2 - x))$ and $g(x) = -f(x)$ about $0$ and $1$ respectively. Both have a finite radius of convergence, as $2$ is an essential singularity. They're both zero on a sequence tending to $2$, but obviously they are different functions. Is this question from somewhere? Have you copied it faithfully and included all relevant context?

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen, thank you for your answer! It's a problem from my friend. I have edited my question.

Comment: I see! You are quite welcome. It's good that you're thinking about things like this! I think this is a very useful example to keep in mind when you are applying the principle of isolated zeroes to things, to illustrate why the limit being inside the domain is so important. Good work on solving the case where it is true yourself, by the way.